# Flutter I/ExoPlayerImpl( 6774): Init dd7b037 [ExoPlayerLib/2.15.0] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, Google, 29] and multiple errors

Tags: android, flutter

My codes were working a few days ago. I deleted the emulator from Android Studio due to a bug in the emulator. Then I created a new emulator. My codes failed in the new emulator.

First of all my codes:

```
  Positioned(
    bottom: 30,
    child: AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: _goButton ? 1 : 0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 25),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const CircleBorder(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 46, 46, 46),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          print("go button clicked");
          if (_clickGoButton) {
            if (_loading == false) {
              setState(() {
                _loading = true;
              });
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 650), () {
                setState(() {
                  ezAnimation.reverse();
                  _secureAndHiddenImage = false;
                });
              });
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1200), () {
                setState(() {
                  _secureAndHiddenHeaders = false;
                  _secureAndHiddenContent = false;
                });
              });
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1800), () {
                setState(() {
                  _goButton = false;
                });
              });
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 2200), () {
                setState(() {
                  PaginationController.pageNumber.value = 3;
                });
              });
            }
            if (_loading == true) {
              print("not loading because loading is true.");
            }
          }
          if (_clickGoButton == false) {
            print("3 saniye bekle amk.");
          }
        }
      )
    )
  )
```

The errors i get:

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 6774): Init dd7b037 [ExoPlayerLib/2.15.0] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, Google, 29]
W/XingSeeker( 6774): XING data size mismatch: 100215, 100087
I/OMXClient( 6774): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  ( 6774): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  ( 6774): codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
D/AudioTrack( 6774): getTimestamp_l(21): device stall time corrected using current time 1714836330000
W/AudioTrack( 6774): getTimestamp_l(21): retrograde timestamp time corrected, 1714850599200 < 1714858399200
D/AudioTrack( 6774): stop(21): called with 65088 frames delivered
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 6774): Release dd7b037 [ExoPlayerLib/2.15.0] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, Google, 29] [goog.exo.core]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing this before. Did you run `flutter clean`, maybe even invalidated caches in Android Studio, etc?

Comment: @dumazy Unfortunately `flutter clean` didn't work. Still same error.